# prove 3rd derivative of a function in a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Let $f$ be twice differentiable and $f'''$ exists in one point $x\in D$. I want to show for this one point $$f'''(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+3h)-3f(x+2h)+3f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^3}$$

I did the following: I know $\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h_1)-f(x)}{h_1}=f'(x)$ and so follows by pluging in $$f''(x)=\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{f'(x+h_2)-f'(x)}{h_2}=...=\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h_1)+f(x-h_1)-2f(x)}{h_1^2}$$

Doing this one more time I'll get ($f'''$ exists in $x$)

$$f'''(x)=\lim_{h_3\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(x+h_3)-f''(x)}{h_3}=...=\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+3h_1)-3f(x+2h_1)+3f(x+h_1)-f(x)}{h_1^3}$$

First question: Can you do it like that?

And my second question: Why can we always choose 'the same $h$' for the limits? Formally for e.g. $f''$ it's

$$\lim_{h_2\rightarrow0}\frac{\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h_1+h_2)-f(x+h_2)}{h_1}-\lim_{h_1\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+h_1)-f(x)}{h_1}}{h_2}$$ and I have $h_1$ and $h_2$ in it.

**Edit**
Using L'Hospital twice on the right side I get
$$\dots=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{3f''(x+3h)-4f''(x+2h)+f''(x+h)}{2h}$$

And so we get $\begin{align}&\dots\\&=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\left\{\frac16\frac{3f''(x+h)-3f''(x)}{h}-\frac13\frac{12f''(x+2h)-12f''(x)}{2h}+\frac12\frac{9f''(x+3h)-9f''(x)}{3h}\right\}\\&=\frac36\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(x+h)-f''(x)}{h}-\frac{12}3\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(x+2h)-f''(x)}{2h}+\frac92\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(x+3h)-f''(x)}{3h}\\&=f'''(x)\end{align}$

Comment: We are looking at the same neighbourhood of $|x| < h$. I may be wrong, but we can use the same $h$ because of continuity (since $f$ is twice differentiable)

Comment: @sizz but this doesn't hold for $h_3$, or am I wrong?

Comment: This approach does not work. You end up with unmanageable triply nested limits. Use Taylor polynomials, as I suggested when you posted this two days ago, and as others are likewise suggesting — because it works ! :)

Comment: @TedShifrin I saw a solution for a formula for the 2nd derivative here: http://math.ucsd.edu/~lni/math140/HW140B_2_solutions.pdf and that's why I did it exactly the same way for the 3rd. Why can't we do it this way?

Comment: I'm guessing a TA wrote that solution. It is incorrect, unless that theorem he refers to is very magical. Nested limits are very subtle unless one has some very detailed arguments (that are related to uniform convergence). For example, in general, it is false that $\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{k\to 0} f(h,k) = \lim_{k\to 0}\lim_{h\to 0} f(h,k)$. In general, knowing that $\lim_{h\to 0} f(h,h) = L$ does NOT prove that $\lim_{h\to 0}\lim_{k\to 0} f(h,k) = L$. Try it with $f(h,k) = \dfrac{hk}{h^2+k^2}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin why not? and are there any cases where you can do my calculating?

Comment: Try my example and try to understand the subtlety. You would need hypotheses that you do *not* have in this problem ... basically some uniform convergence of the difference quotients to the derivatives in question.

Comment: @TedShifrin I understand that there are different results by changing the limits. But I've looked up in a book and found a solution exactly like this one: http://web.ist.utl.pt/duarte.valerio/LAETA2012.pdf I am really confused now. He didn't write two limits but then this one is also wrong!?? & I wonder is there a chance to prove it with L'Hospital? The denominator and numerator are both approaching 0 for $h\rightarrow0$ and you can do it twice since f is twice differentiable.

Comment: You can apply L'Hôpital's rule, but you have to be careful. You can also use L'Hôpital's rule to do $\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$, but that's using L'Hôpital's rule to do the definition of the derivative. Yes, what you found in that book is just plain wrong; it looks like engineering mathematics, not rigorous analysis. If you want to be convinced of the power of Taylor's theorem (and you should learn to appreciate it), find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}\dfrac1{\sin^2x}-\dfrac1{x^2}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I really want to know how L'Hosp. is working here because I've just proved a formula for the 2nd derivative with L'Hos. I can apply L'H. twice on the right side and I get $$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{9f''(x+3h)-12f''(x+2h)+3f''(x+h)}{6h}$$, right? But it's quite hard to find exactly this form on the left side using $$f'''(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f''(x+h)-f(x)}h=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x)-f(x-h)}{h}$$. Any hints?

Comment: Add $-9f''(x)+12f''(x)-3f''(x)$ to the numerator and carefully use limit skills.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've edited the details above. Is this RIGHT? & One more question about my first calculation:By assumption the limit with $h1$ and $h2$ in it exists. Isn't it enough the consider then a subsequence $h_1:=h_2$?

Comment: No, it's NOT enough, because, as I've explained several times, this will not prove the actual limit exists. There are still wrong things above. You should start with your first quantity after the edit and work with it, modifying my hint appropriately. And you really *need* to understand the Taylor approach. It is far superior to L'Hôpital, as you'll find if you try to do the exercise I gave you several posts above.

Comment: @TedShifrin I've tried calculating your example and it's $\frac13$ if I didn't miscalculate. and well what's wrong about adding $-9f''(x)+12f''(x)-3f''(x)=0$ to the numerator, seperating the fractions and putting $\lim$ in front of each because all the limits exists, I can do that, or not?

Comment: It's right but confusing. Since you already divided by $3$, divide my hint by 3$ so it makes more sense. I'm done here.

Comment: @TedShifrin many thanks for your patience!

Answer (score 4):

*This is not a direct answer to your questions but a simple answer to the problem*

By Taylor's theorem  we have
$$f(x+h)=f(x)+hf'(x)+\frac{h^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{h^3}{6}f'''(x)+o(h^3)$$
$$f(x+2h)=f(x)+2hf'(x)+{2h^2}f''(x)+\frac{4h^3}{3}f'''(x)+o(h^3)$$
$$f(x+3h)=f(x)+3hf'(x)+\frac{9h^2}{2}f''(x)+\frac{9h^3}{2}f'''(x)++o(h^3)$$

so we can see easily (*it's a simple calculation)* that 
$$f'''(x)=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x+3h)-3f(x+2h)+3f(x+h)-f(x)}{h^3}$$

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane: Your argument works nicely. One may need to modify the forms of the error terms somewhat, since there is no assumption of $3$ times differentiability in an *interval*.

Comment: @AndréNicolas By verifying the Taylor theorem see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem I think that we must suppose that $f$ is $3$ times differentiable in a nbhd of $x$

Comment: No. You only need three times differentiable *at* $x$. Remember that the Taylor polynomial of degree $3$ at $x$ agrees with $f$ to order $3$ at $x$.

Comment: I think that without the three times differentiability in an interval we still have that the error term is $h^2 \epsilon(h)$ where $\epsilon(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. That should be enough.

Comment: @AndréNicolas But the error term must be expressed with the third derivative of $f$ not with  $\epsilon$ function which we can not controll it. isn't it?

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane No. This is the beauty of Taylor polynomials. For limits, you only need $f(x)-P_3(x) = o(x^3)$, not any error formula.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok but do not forget that the final result is expressed with $f'''$ no?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was sloppy. We need to use the Taylor polynomial *at* $x$. We have $f(x+h)=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac12f''(x)h^2+\frac16f'''(x)h^3+o(h^3)$. Now literally plug into the computation on the RHS.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah ok thanks I have not thought about it since I've always thought to apply Taylor Lagrange. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Nice. But, for folks who aren't familiar with $o(h)$ notation, perhaps you could explain that in your solution. Namely, write the error term as $\epsilon(h)$ with the property that $\lim_{h\to 0} \epsilon(h)/h^3 = 0$. Note you end up $\epsilon(h)$ and $\epsilon(2h)$ and so forth and you have to do a bit of explaining.

Comment: @TedShifrin I appreciate your comment but I don't find a big difference in the two notations and personally I prefer the Landau notation and I think it's a well known notation for the most reader namely who study the Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Well, it's not so well known, although perhaps it should be. For example, in our theoretical calculus courses, I do not teach that notation, and often students don't learn it until graduate school.

Comment: @TedShifrin It's weird in my country ( and we are following the France) we teach this notation in the first undergraduate year so here's a thing where the usa is not the first :)

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane Oh, we're definitely not. And our students are less and less prepared for rigorous mathematics in the university. I stress the concepts (not in a "regular" calculus class, though), but do not teach them the little-oh calculus. There's not enough time, but I'd like to.